# php codeigniter text watermark is not coming

Tags: php, codeigniter

In PHP's CodeIgniter, the text watermarking is not coming. After the code, it showing success, but when I check the output image the text is not shown.

```
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image']='./uploads/user_certificates/certificate_model.jpg';
    $config['new_image']='./uploads/user_certificates/test5.jpg';
    $config['wm_text']='sample text';
    $config['wm_type']="text";
    $config['wm_font_path']="./assets/frontend/webfonts/fa-regular-400.ttf";
    $config['wm_font_size'] = 46;
    $config['wm_font_color'] = '#453344';
    $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'top';
    $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'left';
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->watermark();
    //$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    if (!$this->image_lib->watermark()) {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    } else {
        echo 'Successfully updated image with watermark';
    }
```

Comment: can you store new_image in a different folder like $config['new_image']='./uploads/user_certificates/watermark/test5.jpg'; ?

Comment: I tried. still its not coming

Comment: why there is a dot before the both path string?

Comment: @sreerajt I would suggest you use the full path just to be sure its not trying to save to the wrong location, since `./` will take a relative position from where your PHP file is being accessed from and make sure the destination folder have proper access to write/read to/from.

Comment: Would also note that you're calling `$this->image_lib->watermark()` twice, shouldn't be needed to call it twice, either save it to a variable and reuse the result or just use it within the if and remove the other call you have of it above the if.

Comment: @Prix, I removed the dot and  $this->image_lib->watermark(). but still its not coming

Comment: @sreerajt I never told you to remove a dot, did u read my message fully? I told you to use the fullpath instead of a relative path, aka, `/home/user/public_html/upload/` or whatever the fullpath is for you.

Comment: As @Prix told ya, use and abs path like this `FCPATH.'uploads/whatever'`.